# Using HTML relative addresses in masterpage

Tags: html, asp.net, css, master-pages, relative-path

In my project I have a master page and 2 pages using that master page. One of them is beside the master page in the root folder, and another is inside `'admin'` folder in the root.

The problem is when I use an image in my master page with relative address for example `'images/pic.jpg'`, it is displayed in first page but not in second page.

I can solve this problem by addressing from root folder like this: `'/images/pic.jpg'` but this is not a good idea, as may be my project folder will change in the future.

What should I do for this purpose?

Comment: How about adding this code in the `head`section: `<base href="http://www.DOMAN.com/ROOT_FOLDER/">`. With that code you can still use addresses like `'images/pic.jpg'`

Answer (score 0):

Relative addresses will work only if the folder schema remains the same. Masquad's solution presumes the same...that the file will remain in a folder 1 level below the root and on the same level as the image folder.

If this is not the case, and you change the schema, an absolute address is needed, thereby making 'http://www.example.com/images/pic.jpg' a good idea.